# Posting to a business page from outside facebook?

Tags: facebook, post, external

As the title says, I'm trying to create a web page that allows admins to post to a facebook page, not a profile. How do I go about doing this? I can easily post to my profile wall, but I can't seem to find anything on posting to the business page wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the exact same process to post to a Facebook Page's Wall, but you need to use the Page's ID and not the user's:

```
POST to:
https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed

POST BODY:
access_token={access_token}&message=Hello
```

Make sure you have the "publish_stream" permission from the user.